# Unable to grant role to user

Tags: sql, oracle, roles, sql-grant

I've created a role called `CATDX_OWNER_RPT_RL` and granted SELECT privileges on all tables within the schema. I've created a new user and granted both `CONNECT, CREATE SESSION`. Now I would like to assign the role I created to the new user with the following syntax - `GRANT ROLE CATDX_OWNER_RPT_RL TO USER`. It returns this error `SQL Error: ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege
00990. 00000 -  "missing or invalid privilege"`

Comment: Supply the full script. You've likely just mis-typed the name of the role.

Answer (score 2):

Reinventing the wheel? Omit `ROLE`.

```
GRANT CATDX_OWNER_RPT_RL TO NEW_USER;
```